# tex4ebook (or htlatex) doesn't treat (mathematical) accents properly?

Tags: tex4ht, accents, htlatex, tex4ebook

I tried some codes like

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Let's see $\widehat{\mathcal F}=\hat F=\bar F=\tilde F=\overline F$.
\end{document}
```

with default compilation. Only `\overline` is rendered correctly. I look into the generated html code, it seems to me that these accents are taken into account (there is a code `<span class='accentwidehat'>...</span>`), but usual browsers don't take this into account. Any workaround for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are targeting eBooks with poor MathML and even CSS support, I guess the only universal fix is to use images for math. Try the `pic-m` option for converting all inline math to images:

```
tex4ebook filename.tex "pic-m"
```

The result:

[image]

There ale also some undocumented options that requires images for accented characters:

```
tex4ebook filename.tex "new-accents,accent-,mathaccent-"
```

Beware that it may request pictures even for accented characters in text, which may be undesirable.

Edit:

I've extracted code for picture accents from `tex4ht` sources. It should keep text accents normal. Try the following config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,new-accents}
\Configure{HAccent}\vec{}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
\Configure{HAccent}\widehat{}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
  \Configure{HAccent}\bar{}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
  \Configure{HAccent}\hat{AEIOUaeiou{}}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
  \Configure{HAccent}\tilde{AOaoNn{}}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
\Configure{HAccent}\widetilde{}{\Picture+{}}{\EndPicture}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

edit2:

There seems to be clash between `new-accents` and `babel`. In this case, we can try to redefine the accent commands to use  pictures directly:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\def\patchaccent#1{%
  \csletcs{orig#1}{#1}
  \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname##1{\Picture+{}\csname orig#1\endcsname{##1}\EndPicture}
}
\patchaccent{widehat}
\patchaccent{hat}
\patchaccent{bar}
\patchaccent{tilde}
\patchaccent{overline}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: I wonder whether we have a finer control of what should be converted to images. pic-m is usually not satisfactory. By the way, by "browsers", I mean not only ebook viewers but also web browsers. I load the generated html file by Firefox and Chromium, and neither of these browsers recognizes accentwidehat (I mean, technically, the generated code of *accentwidehat* is not recognized by web browsers, rather than not generating codes).

Comment: @FrankScience I meant that MathML is not supported by browsers. I don't think math accents are really possible to emulate using pure CSS and HTML. especially when the accent  is over multiple letters.

Comment: OK, so I wonder whether there are tricks to specify several commands to be converted into images. I noticed that even if I don't enable `pic-m`, some parts of inline math formulae are converted into images.

Comment: @FrankScience I've updated my answer with some new options

Comment: Thanks. I wonder whether I can hack several 4ht files in `texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht`, like `html0.4ht`, `html32.4ht`, `html4.4ht` to override the default settings. I found that the code about `\widehat` appears at `\:CheckOption{new-accents}`.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is something wrong in these default settings. For example, if I put the code `\bar F` outside the math environment and compile it with tex4ebook without `new-accents` option, it **won't** complain any errors while pdflatex will complain. I believe that the code about `\:CheckOption{accent-}` should be passed no matter whether `new-accents` is right there.

Comment: @FrankScience the `accent-` uses configuration that it available only with the `new-accents` option. and it requires pictures for normal text accents, which is undesirable. but it is possible to extract just the math accent configuration to a `.cfg` file, see the updated answer

Comment: It seems to me that `new-accents` will render `\'e` as `'e` rather than `é` outside math env?

Comment: @FrankScience not if you use the  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. I would also add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I can just enable `new-accents` and `accent-` (everything in `accent-` seems to be valid only under math env?), which won't make pictures normal text accents. By the way, I enable `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}` in configure file, is that okay (namely, not breaking anything even under complicated circumstances)?

Comment: @FrankScience yes, it should work this way.

Comment: I found that the option `new-accents` conflicts with the package babel. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @FrankScience I've provided a new config file

Comment: @michal.h21 As usual, u great....

Comment: patch for `overline` is not needed. I think the commands in `accent-` are all mathematical accents. I put the `overline` in my test case to show a contrary.

Comment: It seems to me that this patch does not work for section titles. For example, `\section{test $\tilde O$}` will lead to `! Argument of \im:g has an extra }`. Any fix for this?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I see. I can only think about using the optional argument with simpler contents (ie. without math)

Comment: How to patch this code so that it works with optional arguments (or better, \texorpdfstring in hyperref package)? Thins like `\section[X]{$\tilde X$]` or `\section{\texorpdfstring{$\tilde X$}X}` still lead to errors.

Comment: I come back to this early question. I find that the treatment of these mathematical accents are very inconsistent and error-prone. For example, if I turn on `new-accents,accent-` to compile a code like `$\tilde O\tilde X$`. I find that `\tilde O` is compiled as `~O` while `\tilde X` is compiled correctly.

Comment: And it seems to me that `new-accents` and `babel` are not essentially clash. The only problem seems to be located in `unicode.4ht`, where the part `\ConfigureHinput{babel}` does not include something like `\:CheckOption{new-accents}\if:Option\else` as in `html0.4ht`, say, to ignore several codes. (By the way, the TeX codes in these `.4ht` files are indented pretty bad).